# How to build catkin compatible third party library in catkin workspace?

Tags: ros, library, build, third-party

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the recommendations for allowing a third-party library (which I maintain) to be built in the ROS ecosystem, by adding the relevant package.xml file and corresponding install target.
However, I would like now to build a ros node which depends on this package and therefore would like this third-party library to be built inside my catkin workspace. I have moved my third-party library to the source space of my catkin workspace, but now catkin_make complains:

This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build
a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.

How can I make catkin_make to invoke catkin_make_isolated for these non-catkin packages automatically? Otherwise, what is the usual practice in these cases? I would like to avoid maintaining different catkin workspaces since it complicates the workflow

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189545/how-to-build-catkin-compatible-third-party-library-in-catkin-workspace?/) by [Matias](https://answers.ros.org/users/11721/matias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2014-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to use `catkin_make_isolated` if your workspace contains a non-catkin / plain CMake package.

Rational: `catkin_make` uses a single CMake invocation for the whole workspace. With a non-catkin package in the workspace that is conceptionally not possible hence you have to build all packages in isolation.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matias](https://answers.ros.org/users/11721/matias/) on 2015-06-26**:
I ended up switching to catkin-tools, which solves this nicely.